# Retrieve Test Cases related to release

Tags: rally, appsdk2

How I can retrieve Test Cases that related to some release.

I want to retrieve data about Test Cases that related to Release.
But Test Case doesn't have Release filed. Btw, Test Case has WorkProduct it's the for which this test case was created. But when I'm trying to get the WorkProdut from test case object, 
I don't have any useful information except US name, actually I can use this Name for getting legal US object.

But it looks difficult...

Answer (score 0):

TestCases get scheduled into Iterations and Releases via TestSets. I have an app in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/stories-testsets-by-release) that builds a grid of stories scheduled for release, and testsets scheduled for release and associated testcases.

Here is the code fragment where TestSet objects are loaded, with their TestCases collection, and then TestCases collection is hydrated (since this cannot be done in a single request):

```
    _makeAnotherStore: function(){
        Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                model: 'TestSet',
                fetch: ['FormattedID', 'TestCases', 'TestCaseStatus'],  
                pageSize: 100,
                autoLoad: true,
                filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()],
                listeners: {
                    load: this._onTestSetsLoaded,
                    scope: this
                }
            }); 
    },
     _onTestSetsLoaded: function(store, data){
        console.log('store...',store);
    console.log('data...',data);
        var testSets = [];
        var pendingTestCases = data.length;
         console.log(data.length);
         if (data.length ===0) {
            this._createTestSetGrid(testSets);  
         }
         Ext.Array.each(data, function(testset){ 
            var ts  = {
                FormattedID: testset.get('FormattedID'),   
                _ref: testset.get('_ref'),  
                TestCaseStatus: testset.get('TestCaseStatus'),
                TestCaseCount: testset.get('TestCases').Count,
                TestCases: []
            };
            var testCases = testset.getCollection('TestCases');
            testCases.load({
                                fetch: ['FormattedID'],
                                callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(testcase){
                                        ts.TestCases.push({_ref: testcase.get('_ref'),
                                                        FormattedID: testcase.get('FormattedID')
                                                    });
                                    }, this);
                                    --pendingTestCases;
                                    if (pendingTestCases === 0) {
                                        this._createTestSetGrid(testSets);
                                    }
                                },
                                scope: this
                            });
            testSets.push(ts);
     },this);
 }
```

,